# How to vertically center a font-awesome icon?

Tags: html, css

In the following example, I would like to center the `fa-plus` icon inside the circle.

[image]

What I notice is the glyph is aligned with the top of the `<i>` tag. However I have added everything that should be needed to align it vertically:

https://jsfiddle.net/x2n13p4e/2/

HTML:

```
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" href="#">
    <i class="btn-glyphicon text-success fa fa-plus"></i>
    Add
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-glyphicon {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    align-items:center;
}

.icon-btn {
    padding: 1px 15px 3px 2px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Remove `height: 1.5em;`

Comment: @mpsbhat Not really a solution because if I force a `width` of `2em`, I therefore need to set a `height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `position: relative`, you make the icon a *container* for absolute positioned items *inside* of it **or** for pseudo classes, like `:before` or `:after`.

A absolute positioned item inside of a relative positioned *container* can be centered horizontally and vertically as follows:

```
.center-horizontally-and-vertically {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/3589620)

#### Example

```css
.btn-glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-glyphicon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.icon-btn {
  padding: 1px 15px 3px 2px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" href="#">
  <i class="btn-glyphicon text-success fa fa-plus"></i> Add
</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2n13p4e/53/)

Comment: It works, could you explain why your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
width: 1.5em;
height: 1.5em;
```

try it with:

```
width: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/Lz615auc/2/

Comment: In your `jsfiddle`, the circle is not a circle anymore :(

Comment: @nowox that is because of `padding: 5px`. You could play with it e.g. use `padding: 20px 23px;`. It also depends what the font size is. So try to work with `font-size` as well. https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/Lz615auc/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `line-height` property in `.btn-glyphicon` class.

```
.btn-glyphicon {
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle !important;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: @nowox remove `padding: 3x;` for `line-height` to work well